# generating series of number 0,3,5,8,10,13,15,18

Tags: ios, objective-c, numbers, generate-series

i want to generate a series of number through looping.

my series will contain numbers like  0,3,5,8,10,13,15,18 and so on.

i try to take reminder and try to add 2 and 3 but it wont work out.

can any one please help me in generating this series.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an increment which toggles between 3 and 2, e.g.

```
for (i = 0, inc = 3; i < 1000; i += inc, inc = 5 - inc)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the the sequence starts at zero, and uses increments of 3 and 2. There are several ways of implementing this, but perhaps the simplest one would be iterating in increments of 5 (i.e. 3+2) and printing two numbers - position and position plus three.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
i = 0
REPEAT N times :
    PRINT i
    PRINT i + 3
    i += 5
```

- The iteration `i=0` will print `0` and `3`
- The iteration `i=5` will print `5` and `8`
- The iteration `i=10` will print `10` and `13`
- The iteration `i=15` will print `15` and `18`
- ... and so on

Answer (score 0):

I was pulled in with the tag [generate-series](/questions/tagged/generate-series), which is a powerful PostgreSQL function. This may have been tagged by mistake (?) but it just so happens that there would be an **elegant solution**:

```sql
SELECT ceil(generate_series(0, 1000, 25) / 10.0)::int;
```

- `generate_series()` returns `0, 25, 50, 75 , ...` (can only produces integer numbers)
- division by `10.0` produces `numeric` data: `0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, ...`
- `ceil()` rounds up to your desired result.
- The final cast to integer (`::int`) is optional.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3029)